How to assign the name to anonymous volume which `COPY` command of the Docker creates?
Project structure

Well, most of files does not matter.
The actual files are:

docker-compose.yml (see listing below)
FrontServer.Dockerfile (see listing below)
package.json

docker-compose.yaml
The Database service does not matter for this question, but I have mention it to avoid this service being suspected.
version: "3.5"

services:

  front_server:

    image: example-front_server-staging
    container_name: Example-FrontServer-Staging
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "FrontServer.Dockerfile"
    ports: [ "442:442" ]

    depends_on: [ Database ]
    command: sh -c "npm run \"Database migration\" && node FrontServerEntryPoint.js --environment staging"

  Database:

    image: postgres:16.2
    container_name: Example-Database-Staging
    ports: [ "5431:5432" ]

    environment:

      - TZ="Asia/Tokyo"
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=EXAMPLE-NOTHING_TO_STEAL

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/data/example.jp

volumes:
  DatabaseData:
    name: Example-DatabaseData-Staging
    driver: local

FrontServer.Dockerfile
According the idea, each container and volume related with this image intended to be disposed after one-time usage. No important data stored inside. If some changes will be applied to source code, the new container and volume with executable code must be independent from previous one.
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/example.com

COPY . /var/www/example.com

RUN npm install --no-package-lock

Problem
Each time when I am executing docker compose, the COPY . /var/www/example.com creates something volume-like (is it volume or no, it is being listed via docker volume list) with long name:
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     7bc56f377f45dff804abc633569757ac7c26d7a77305e91dd83338e4bdbb903d
local     3793cc2338491d5065cb81e14e64bde20f2f8fc87dcc393r47d774a0e1f92493

How I can assign the meaningful name to these ones?

I cannot reproduce the behaviour; starting the container does not create a volume on my machine. Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository?

The setup you show has no volumes, anonymous or otherwise.  Is the anonymous volume possibly coming from the database container?

@Turing85, Thank you for the comment. Sorry for the information shortage. I have shared the project structure and the full listing of "docker-compose.yaml". Is it enough?

@DavidMaze, Thank you for the comment. " Is the anonymous volume possibly coming from the database container?". - No. The Database service has the named volume, the DatabaseData. I have shared the full listing of docker-compose.yaml.

Can you try changing - Example-DatabaseData-Staging:/data/example.jp to - DatabaseData:/data/example.jp?

The anonymous volume is in fact coming from the Database container.
The postgres image, like most other standard database images, declares a Dockerfile VOLUME for its data directory /var/lib/postgresql/data.  Since your Compose file doesn't explicitly mount anything there, Docker automatically creates an anonymous volume at startup time and mounts it.
If the DatabaseData named volume is intended to hold the actual data, then you need to change its mount point to where PostgreSQL expects to find it
services:
  Database:
    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

If that volume contains some sort of seed data or is otherwise referenced directly from SQL calls, then you may need to create a second named volume and mount it on the standard data directory.

Thank you for the answer! You right, it was because of Posgres data directory /var/lib/postgresql/data.  I was went by the wrong way thinking about this volume has been caused by the front_server... It was impossible to know about such Posgres image behavior at advance without reading the documentation, wasn't it?
